# Display articles in Wordpress from a 2nd database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm looking to move a client to Wordpress, but the current site has a database for articles of which there are more than 2000. The client doesn't want to lose these and the time involved turning them into Wordpress posts will take too long.
The articles have 4 data points that need to be displayed: heading, date, intro and article.

I have managed to create a page that displays the heading and dates as links, with the article id in the link. How do I now proceed to display the article as a post when the link is clicked. It doesn't look like Custom Post Types are what I'm looking for.

My coding skills are very basic and my understanding of Wordpress core is even worse.

Hope someone can shed some light for me.

Comment: I think CPT are exactly what you are looking for. That eliminates the need to fish around in outside WP databases to begin with. Your four data points can be stored as custom meta data.

Comment: @CBroe
And how do you propose I transfer the data from the existing database to custom metadata? I have a database with all the data I need. I'm just looking for a solution to call and display those 4 data points when I click on the corresponding URL.

Comment: If you have this in a database already, then converting it is likely a job that could be done via SQL, otherwise there’s importer plugins like WP All Import. _“I'm just looking for a solution to call and display those 4 data points when I click on the corresponding URL”_ - write a script that gets the ID passed as a GET parameter, and displays the corresponding content. If you need it integrated into WP directly, then look into how to add to its routing system also maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I had the URL's passing the ID and was using GET. Seems my problem was in the code calling the parameters. They were being passed, but I was struggling to get them to display. Finally got the code correct.